Problem populating Street Address field using javascript in console on USPS Click-N-Ship web site
I am having a problem populating one field on the USPS Click-N_Ship web site from the console using Javascript.
I can populate First, Middle and Last Names, City, State, and Zip code, and even the Apartment field, but cannot populate the Street Address field. I suspect this is because the Street Address is a lookup field.
This code:
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.firstName"]').value = "Jay";
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.middleInitial"]').value = "A";
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.lastName"]').value = "Talbott";
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.addressLine2"]').value = "Apt 3.";
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.city"]').value = "Denver";
document.getElementById('recipient-state').value = 'CO'
document.querySelector('input[name="recipient.zip9"]').value = "80601";


Will produce the expected results filling in the appropriate fields.
The elements of the Street Address are shown in the image.
Can someone tell me what javascript I need to use to populate the Street Address field?
Thank you.
I have tried document.getElementById('recipient-addressLine1') and variations thereof without any luck..
[elements of Street Address field]
: https://i.sstatic.net/AbC69M8J.png

looks like #recipient-addressLine1 input.rbt-input-main would be the selector

@JaromandaX Thank you.

This does work to an extent:


document.querySelector('#recipient-addressLine1 input.rbt-input-main').value = '100 N. Jackson St.';


but after the address appears in the text box, it completely disappears. I suspect that has something to do with the fact that the text box is a lookup from which the complete address can be selected.

I know that I can manually type an address in that field, even if the address will not bring up a complete address, but I am wondering why the address disappears.
Any thoughts? Again, thank you for your assistance.

not sure why you'd fill the values from the console using Javascript in the first place. Without knowing a lot more about the site, I got nothin
